# UIViewController not responding for some times

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am getting some weird issue in my Project.

I am creating a project which contains some checklist table items.

For this I had a IPadRootViewController class which is parent class of my project, Now i am adding a child viewcontroller Dashboarrootviewcontroller which is having Navigation bar and two view containers which are linked to dashboardviewcontroller and webviewcontroller.

The webViewController is a Hybrid Page which is designed by html and angular JS. For first time app laoded then i am showing webview controller(with full page frame) adding as a child viewcontroller of iPadrootviewcontroller. after this page i am loading dashboardrootviewcontroller which is having dashboardview at left container and webviewcontroller (same instance) at right container. Here right side webviewcontroller contains the detail of an item in dashboardviewcontroller's table.

In dashboardviewcontroller i am having a tableview and 3 buttons which is used to sort, filter, group for the tableview items.

Firstly i am sending a request to fetch the data from server. After getting response i am parsing and storing it. and then i am loading the table which is a component having a tableview.

I am reloading the dashboardRootview if i am coming back from Full Page WebViewController

I am posting a request to fetch data manually when i am loading dashboardRootviewcontroller.

this time the dashboardviewcontroller is not responding and dashboard table is empty even though all the datasource methods table is printing correct values in console (NSLog).

At same time the background sync from server also starts whenever server database has changes. At this time  i am sending a notification to refetch data from server. This time the dashboardviewcontroller is responding and table is also loading.

My dashboardviewcontroller is not responding to any method (in simulator not in debugging) that will change the UI from Xib, if i send a request other than the way of through notification.

I had noticed that if I press the buttons (FilterBy, SortBy, GroupBy) and select any option then the table is reloading fine.

I am sorry to say that I am unable to show my code.

One more thing i have noticed in debug, whenever i am posting notification to reload the data which i am making request to fetch data from local server and then after getting response i am reloading table.

In both scenarios(with issue and without issue) i am using same order of methods in order to get data from server and then reload table.

Comment: Have u assigned your tableView datasource and delegate to your ViewController?

Comment: Show your code, or you'll get too broad, general, ... answers like 'did you assign your dataSource and delegate?`, etc. No crystal ball ...

Comment: Make sure the `reloadData` call after fetching data from DB happens on main thread. In your case this may be the issue but I can't be sure as there is no code.

Comment: I had assigned my tableview datasource and delegate methods perfectly.
My table is loading data for some times and not reloading for some times. As Amar said there might be Threading issue i will redebug in that scenario. Thank you Dany, Robert and Amar to responding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i came up with Answer to my issue.

All this happend because of multi instances of dashboardviewController.

I had linked dashboardviewcontroller to container view of dashboardRootviewcontroller, and then in my dashboardrootviewcontroller class i am getting it from storyboard using method "instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier" so it is creating a instance and storyboard itself creating an instance.

So these two instances leed to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

call the `[self.tableView reloadData];` method with the name of your table view in

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, But every datasource method is executing perfectly and i am getting perfect values in debugging but it doesn't show any difference in simulator.
And also i need to reload the table whenever i am getting response from server so its not possible to reload in viewwill appear.

Answer (score 0):

1/ Take care that your delegate `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` return the expected values.
Add `NSLog` to print out the values you compute in this methods.

2/ Take care that your tableView is added to your view hierarchy and that the `bounds`, `hidden` and `alpha` properties of your `UITableView` are what you think they are. To do so the easiest way is to put a weird color as `backbroundColor` to your `UITableView`

Let us know if everything in this list is ok.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I am getting perfect data if i tried to print data in debug or in nslog. Each and every data source method is executing with new data as i am seeing in debug. But it is not showing in simulator the tableview is loaded. If i post notification to fetch the data then it is loading.
AS i had already informed that i am using same scenario for both cases (with issue and without issue)

Comment: Also i am not hiding or decreasing alpha value of the table anywhere else.